# android studio changes svg files

Tags: android-studio, svg, icons, android-jetpack-compose

I've downloaded a svg file of UE flag, and it is supposed to look something like this:
[image]

but during the configuration of vector asset in android studio it changes the svg file and causes this:

[image]

Is it because the SVG is too complicated?

(I honestly have no idea, just guessing... I've tried to find a simpler one but I couldn't find any)

[the place where I downloaded the SVG from](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b7/Flag_of_Europe.svg)

Any help will be appreciated, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android Studio has issues with some SVG files and can change their shape. As this is simply a bug inside Android Studio you just have to report it and try to find another SVG file to use for now.

If the image shows correctly on the Android Studio image preview but not in your app, then it means your image loading library has an issue with the vector image and you should report it to the developer.

I have experienced both and the only actual fix on your side is to just find another SVG file unfortunately.

Comment: it doesn't look as it is supposed to do in app and in android studio unfortunately

Comment: So it's broken on Android Studio. Nothing you can do except reporting it and finding another SVG for now.

Comment: I've already submitted a report and have been working on an replacement svg, thanks for your help :)